# finding the student and teacher with the most courses in common

Tags: mysql

I need to find which teacher and student have the most overlapping courses (if any) using a MySQL script. I have built my own DB with the following tables:
Students (id, first name, last name)
Professors (id, first name, last name)
Courses (id, name)
Grades (student id, course id, assignment, grade)

Thought Process:

I need to list the students, teachers and courses:

```sql
    select distinct students.first_name, professors.first_name, course_name from grades
    join students on grades.student_id = students.student_id
    join courses on grades.course_id = courses.course_id
    join professors on courses.professor_id = professors.professor_id
```

[image: Result of above query]

Now I need to look through the information to find which student is taking multiple courses from the same professor. I just don't know how to implement that in MySQL.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  resul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your query as a base to start, you can `group by` student and professor to get the number of common courses. 
The below query returns the students and professors that have the most common courses:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    #I had to alias these column names to avoid a duplicate column name error (Quito)
    students.first_name, students.last_name,
    professors.first_name, professors.last_name, 
    count(distinct courses.id) counter 
  from grades
  join students on grades.student_id = students.student_id
  join courses on grades.course_id = courses.course_id
  join professors on courses.professor_id = professors.professor_id
  group by 
    students.first_name, students.last_name,
    professors.first_name, professors.last_name
)

select * from cte
where cte.counter = (
  select max(counter) from cte
)
```

Comment: That's it! But is there a way to not have the result set multiplied by 4? Hellee and Elmcooke both 2 classes with Mopointy, but the query result says 8 for the counter. That's because of the joining right? Can I fix that with coalesce?

Comment: I used the `having counter > 1` with the `distinct` call. I get the correct result. I'm trying to incorporate `max` to only show the highest (in case there are different connections; like a 3 or 4 as well).

Comment: Don't you need only 1 row with the maximum number of common courses? This can be done via order by. Max() would need further grouping.

Comment: I need to find the student(s) who are taking more than one class from a professor. It could be that more than one student (in this case) fits. But I'm thinking universal for another data set that maybe there are some students with 3 or 4 classes. And if there are more than one with the highest value, I need to show just them. Right now, with `counter > 1` it will show all with 2 or more classes. How can I show the students with the max value for the counter? I put it around the count statement and said `invalid use of group function`.

Comment: `having counter > 1` was my initial answer and I edited to `order by counter desc limit 1` to give just the student and professor with the maximum number of common courses. Doesn't it work?

Comment: It does. but in this case there are two students who have 2 common courses. How would I show just the students with the max of counter? What if there were 5 students who had 2 common courses?

Comment: What is the version of Mysql?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190529/discussion-between-quito-guillermos-and-forpas).